# Overriding a class defined in Spring Boot \ Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

We are in the process of migrating a legacy application to Spring Boot. In order to continue with testing until we have assigned roles to users, I would like to override the following:

**class**: `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper`

**method**: `public boolean isUserInRole(String role)`

I have created a new class which extends `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper` and overrides `isUserInRole()`, as follows:

```
@Component
public class MySecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper extends org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper {

    public MySecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request,
            AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver, String rolePrefix) {
        super(request, trustResolver, rolePrefix);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        return true;
    }
```

When the application is run, the new bean does not take the place of the existing `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper` class. This is clear because when the new class is instantiated, the constructor is not injected with the beans being injected into `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper`. The application fails to start because parameters of type `AuthenticationTrustResolver` and `String` to the new class `MySecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrappercould` could not be found

What is the correct way to override `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper`, or for that matter any class in the Spring Boot framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper` class is ultimately used by the `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter` configured with `http.servletApi()`. Some information about this feature is available in the [Spring Security reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/servlet-api.html#servletapi-user-in-role).

This feature shields you from direct dependence on Spring Security and provides *very* high level integration with Spring Security through the Servlet API. You cannot directly influence the class used to wrap the request.

However, if you wish to temporarily modify the result of role checks, you can influence what roles are available in the `Authentication` object during authentication itself. See info in the docs on [GrantedAuthority](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#servlet-authentication-granted-authority), and note that you will want to customize roles during authentication by providing a custom `UserDetailsService`.